# HP touchscreen malfunctioning in Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 22.04, display, xinput

I understand there are a large amount of questions regarding disabling the touchscreens and I've yet to find a useful answer from any of them.
I have come so far as to find what seems to be the correct file for the actual touchscreen, however, I am unsure for general lack of knowledge for how these drivers are placed in the filesystem.

I ran the following to find the file
`sudo xinput list`
This returned what I already knew to be what I want disabled.

`G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]`

I then ran the following three separate inputs to no avail.

```
sudo xinput disable 9
sudo xinput --disable G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP
sudo xinput disable G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP
```

None of those commands worked so I searched around to find some random chance that I'd be able to identify the source file for my issue. I found the following commands.

`sudo modprobe -r hid multitouch`, and separately I tried `lsusb`

The `lsusb` command returned a resulting statement of the following.

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2a94:5009 G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP
```

Once I did that, I followed someones answer to a similar question and manually searched for the pathway of:

`/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic` (this is odd because they didn't a "hid-generic" file.)

I ran the `ls -l` command and it gave me this exceptionally weird block of information that I have zero clue of how to identify.

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 27 01:56 0003:2A94:5009.0003 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:2A94:5009.0003
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 27 01:56 0003:2A94:5009.0004 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:2A94:5009.0004
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 01:56 bind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 27 01:56 module -> ../../../../module/hid_generic
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 01:56 new_id
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jan 26 03:50 uevent
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 01:56 unbind
```

Hopefully this is nothing important that I should be keeping secure, but I'm at a loss for words on how difficult this has been to turn a touchscreen off/on.
Regardless if this is too much information or not, I figured it would be best to walk the reader through every step I've taken so far. Just in case of the possibility that I messed something up.
Can someone please help me figure out what I'm looking at so I can get this touchscreen disabled, before I haphazardly wipe 3-4 more hours of education off of my screen in the wrong press of the screen. Thank you :)